# OCR Not giving the right output

Tags: python, ocr

I am using OCR to read the number that is present on the picture: [image]

but it gives me this output : |, but I want this as output: 0068,768

Does anyone know what I need to do to tweak this? It is working fine when I write in word 123 and use that picture as input, but not the picture that I have added here.

This is the code that I am using now:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract
  
# Defining paths to tesseract.exe
# and the image we would be using
path_to_tesseract = r"tesseract.exe"
image_path = r"capture.png"
  
# Opening the image & storing it in an image object
img = Image.open(image_path)
  
# Providing the tesseract executable
# location to pytesseract library
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
  
# Passing the image object to image_to_string() function
# This function will extract the text from the image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  
# Displaying the extracted text
print(text[:-1])
```

Comment: Tesseract works well on black print text on white backgrounds. For this case you either need to preprocess the image, or you could use models used to OCR scene text. [Some](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) [examples](https://github.com/faustomorales/keras-ocr) [linked](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR).

Comment: hi Adriaansen, I have used 2 examples and both of them gives totally different numbers then what I have on my picture. Do you know why it doesn't recognize it correct?

Comment: Depends on what these models were trained on, some may confuse digits for letters. PaddleOCR seems to work fine, check [this demo](https://huggingface.co/spaces/robin0307/PaddleOCR)

Comment: The demo was working fine, but the code gives me again not the correct numbers :/

Comment: When you go to files, app.py in the demo you can copy and reuse the code that works! Or you could fit clone the demo

Comment: *git clone the demo